# Windows Search bar fills background with black color

Tags: windows-10, windows-search

Today I launched my laptop, and when I hit the 3-finger gesture to open the search box, it blacked out the whole screen and then popped in the left part of my screen, taking more space than usual. It seemed weird to me, so I restarted. After restart, the problem seems to have gone, but not completely. Now I was able to capture a little bit of it. Once I again use a 3-finger gesture to pop up the search menu, it first fills up the space needed with black colour and then proceeds to animate. Here is a screenshot:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Hlt9.png)

As you can see here, gray background is filling up blank black space. Is there something wrong with my pc or just random bug of windows? My laptop is pretty fresh so I wouldn't like to allow any kind of virus or something into it.

EDIT

Oh okay, I got first case after restarting explorer [first case screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPCCF.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also have had that problem, and it seems to me as though it sometimes just appears. Restarting explorer and the computer always works for me. It is most probably a problem with Windows, similar to some bugs with the taskbar disappearing in Windows 11.

Comment: So I can be sure that there's nothing actually wrong with system in this context?

Comment: @YuriyKirel You can never be 100% sure, but in this case, I would be 99% certain that the problem is in the OS. When your computer is so new, it probably is nothing wrong. However, I have experienced some issues with the taskbar due to StartAllBack (installed application), so you might want to see if you have some weird apps installed altering the search bar and/or taskbar.

Comment: I see. I rarely install weird apps, so hopefully it's just some weird stuff going on because of updates. Thank you